# Viewpager error

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with several pages.

For some reason it fails when changing from one screen to another (either using the PageIndicator, the Back button or just sliding from one page to another).

Sometimes it fails really quick, other times I have to change many times really fast for it to happen.

I get an "**unfortunately, MyApp has stopped**" message. There is nothing else.
I think it is not a problem in my app because sometimes it works well for many tries moving from one page to the other.

In the emulator and in my tablet works always good. In my S3 and S4 fails as I said before.

Can anyone give me some light here?

EDIT: This is my log:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 792bef18

backtrace:
00 pc 00007304 /system/lib/libui.so
01 pc 00007461 /system/lib/libui.so (android::Region::createTJunctionFreeRegion(android::Region const&)+54)
02 pc 0001bb13 /system/lib/libhwui.so
03 pc 0001b2d1 /system/lib/libhwui.so
04 pc 0001df1b /system/lib/libhwui.so
05 pc 0001e079 /system/lib/libhwui.so
06 pc 0006c689 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07 pc 00020d4c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
08 pc 000519ef /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
09 pc 0002a1e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
10 pc 00031690 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
11 pc 0002ed28 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
12 pc 00064139 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
13 pc 0006c4f3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
14 pc 0002a1e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
15 pc 00031690 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
16 pc 0002ed28 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
17 pc 00063e55 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
18 pc 0004d5d7 /system/lib/libdvm.so
19 pc 000522ff /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
20 pc 00053893 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
21 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
22 pc 0000e4f3 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
23 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process
```

Comment: and where´s the code or messages displayed in logcat?

Comment: I got the log and edited my question